# How to set azure-function app port from docker -e variable?

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, azure-functions

I'm trying to create azure queue listener in docker and deploy it as an azure function.

Azure runs my docker with command similar to following:

```
docker run -d -p 16506:8081 --name queue-listener_0 -e PORT=8081 ...
```

The only thing that I need to do is to get that port variable and put it to `func start --port $PORT` field in entrypoint script, but the problem is that the bash doesn't see variables put through -e key.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tarampampam/node:10.10-alpine as buildContainer


COPY package.json package-lock.json entrypoint.sh host.json extensions.csproj proxies.json /app/
COPY /QueueTrigger/function.json /app/
#COPY /app/dist /app/dist

### only for local launch
#COPY  /local.settings.json /app


WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:2.0
WORKDIR /app
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/app
ENV AzureWebJobs_ExtensionsPath=/app/bin

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/package.json /app/

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/dist /app/
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/function.json /app/QueueTrigger/
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/bin /app/bin
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/entrypoint.sh /app
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/host.json /app
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/extensions.csproj /app
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/proxies.json /app
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/resources /app/resources

### only for local launch
#COPY --from=buildContainer /app/local.settings.json /app


RUN chmod 755 /app/entrypoint.sh
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
RUN npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@core --unsafe-perm true
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ghostscript && gs -v

# Serve the app
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

Entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/bash

func start --port $PORT
```

Comment: What is your `Dockerfile` like, are you running `func start ....` in the container?

Comment: @ahmelsayed, I added the dockerfile code to my question. What about running the app, yes, I run it inside docker in entrypoint script

Comment: As I know, not all the docker image are supported for function. You can see [Supported base images for Azure Functions](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-base?tab=description) from the [Create a function on Linux using a custom image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image).

Comment: @CharlesXu but I used exactly supported image from Microsoft official docker hub, didn't I?

Comment: Where is this container running? In AppService or AKS? Either way, everything looks good. It should work.

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT, container is running In Azure Function and, If I'm not mistaken, It's the same conditions as In AppService. The point is that, Inside ENTRYPOINT script I can reach only build time env variables, but not Injected via -e during launch

Comment: Hmm... That is weird. Can't think of a reason for why it's not accessible without trying it out. Any specific reason for using `func` instead of the runtime directly?

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT ```func``` is smth like special azure function launcher. But, actually, it doesn't make sense. I tried to echo all ```env``` variables in entrypoint.sh and I could see only build time vars.  And yeah, that is weird :))

Comment: I don't think using `func` is recommended as such on Azure. Its really for local development. You should let the runtime in the container run instead.

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT, does it mean that I should leave entrypoint.sh empty?

Comment: Yes. That's how the default `dockerfile` generated by `func` is too.

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT I tried it out, didn't work. The app didn't launch

Answer (score 2):

`func` is more for local development.

The `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:2.0` image already has the runtime packaged with the default entrypoint set to start it. You really don't need `func` here.

**But**, if ever required, even with just the runtime, you can customize the port

1. You would have to remove these last few lines from the container

```
RUN chmod 755 /app/entrypoint.sh
RUN npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@core --unsafe-perm true

# Serve the app
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

2. And run your container like this

```sh
docker run -d -p 16506:8081 --name queue-listener_0 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8081 ...
```

> Note that `local.settings.json` won't be picked up by the runtime. Your App Settings would have to be set manually as environment variables.

Comment: I guess I cannot customize the command running application because azure launches the container by itself. But I will try out build docker without last rows

Comment: Yes. The command is mostly useful if you are trying to run it on a custom docker host or AKS instead.